# Broken HTML inside an HTML page

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a page where I am reading an HTML from email.

Sometimes, the text which comes from the email has HTML and CSS and it changes my page style completely.

I don’t want my page style to be impacted because of this. How do I read the HTML and CSS strictly inside a particular `div` (box) and not let the page get impacted by this?

Comment: simple, use inline css..and if necessary then use !important too.but be careful with !important.

Comment: or put the HTML inside an iframe

Comment: I don't have control over HTML that is getting displayed within my page. I just want to contain that HTML whatever i receive within a particular div and not let it impact outside the div.

Comment: Then I think you need to add some css for that main div in which you are going to show email contents.

Comment: I think that the iframe is the best solution. If you write css with !important for all maybe you can autodestroy your project

Comment: Adding HTML in a page can cause anything because of the `style` element (and `link`). It's even _funnier_ with the `script` element if the emails you display are from unknown sources ("funny" as in spams in a webmail; rendering them as is is an obvious security problem, vs your newsletter copy pasted in an HTML page which is a trusted source - you)

Answer (score 0):

you have to write your css using some parent > child format. You might have to use !important.

Comment: I am using Admin LTE theme and haven't written the css from scratch

Comment: If your email HTML can have a container and css is written in parent > child fashion.  Then it will solve your problem

Comment: Here are my file. Correct: jamboreebliss.com/testabc/AdminLTE1/pages/UI/timeline1.html Incorrect: jamboreebliss.com/testabc/AdminLTE1/pages/UI/timeline2.html because of email content page styling is changing

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using some kind of common selectors like "a", "p", "div". In these cases we can prevent the overriding by using parent class/id or with "!important.". I will not recommend the second one.

Ex. using parent className:

```
.parent-classname p{
    /*style here*/
}
```

Comment: Here are my file. Correct: http://jamboreebliss.com/testabc/AdminLTE1/pages/UI/timeline1.html Incorrect: http://jamboreebliss.com/testabc/AdminLTE1/pages/UI/timeline2.html because of email content page styling is changing

Answer (score 0):

put that div in iframe so it behave like a seperate window so your html content not effected by loadded css.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<iframe></iframe>` tag instead of the `<div></div>`. Using Parent>Child Css format will also help make your styles more unique and  protect them from being overridden.